# Include h2 mode limit in application properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

after upgrading h2 to 2.1.x , cucumber test cases failed where the query had limit getting included for pagination

asc [*]limit ?
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)

there was reference

https://groups.google.com/g/h2-database/c/yxnv64Ak-u8 and few post in stackoverflow (JpaRepository - Oracle Pagination - Limit and Offset) mentioning limit to set true programmatically

but i want to include like a property in application.properties

i have set MODE=MSSQLSERVER in spring.datasource.url , still im not sure how to include it in property file

Comment: You need to upgrade Hibernate ORM together with H2, old versions don't work well with new versions of H2.